# Can you get info on how karma is mapping a given request?

Tags: karma-runner

I'm having issues debugging my karma config file. I'm getting 404s I do not expect and would like to figure out what file locations are being tried to resolve a given request.

Is there a way to get this information? If no flag for this is available, is there a `console.log` I could place in the karma source to get the desired result?

## Edit: Why I'm asking this

I have run into this issue quite a few times when using karma plugins such as jspm-karma. The issue ultimately boils down to the fact that requests to `/foo/bar.js` are not being mapped to the proper file locations. I am looking for how to get any amount of transparency into this the next time it occurs.

Ultimately I assume there *must* be either a flag or a line of code I can insert that would log something similar to

```
Requested /foo/bar.js
  Trying /Users/gmauer/code/blah/foo/bar.js...(not found)
  Trying /Users/gmauer/code/blah/tests/foo/bar.js...(not found)
Response 404
```

How do karma and karma plugin developers debug these issues?

Comment: Could you show the code and the errors you having now

Comment: @bigluis ... I'm not sure what you mean honestly. You could point out the specific error (and it might come to that) but I'm trying to figure out how to debut this sort of error into the future.

Answer (score -1):

Can you not use the `browserConsoleLogOptions`?

https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

That setting should allow you to control the browser's log output, so you can see which URL requests are being attempted.

Comment: Daniel, I tried adding `browserConsoleLogOptions: { level: 'debug' }` but am not seeing any messages beyond what I saw before. Is this something that works for you? It certainly doesn't show what paths are being tried to serve the file that 404s. In fact putting `terminal: false` seems to still not affect anything...

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid I haven't used karma-runner, but from reading the docs, the browserConsoleLogOptions should set the log file for the browser that is spawned to run the tests - this should contain the same errors that you'd normally see when running in a browser, which would include the URLs being requested. Can you confirm if the log output contains information from any console.log commands in your code?

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question entirely from top to bottom Daniel. I'm not asking about errors logged to the browser console I'm asking about how to debug configuration errors when karma cannot find a file.

Comment: Oh, so it's the server side that can't find the file? OK, I must have completely misunderstood. Not sure why you'd be getting a 404 though? Surely that would be client side?